# Why can't I resolve implicitly?

Tags: c#, implicit

I always right click to resolve the namespace implicitly.

But for some namespace, I cannot resolve it implicitly and have to resolve it explicitly, leading to code like program1.logging.ErrorLogger.ErrorArise. Why can't I resolve implicitly?

Comment: This is because there is a class from a different namespace having the same name, so you need to be explicit about which you want.
So there is a good chance, there is another class called ErrorArise with its namespace defined in the usings.

Comment: show a bit of code, im sure i can help

Answer (score 3):

Check this fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Px9BQ

The problem is, there are two or more classes sharing the same name, so its not implicitly possible to know which you refer to, hence you need to specifiy the name explicit, by providing its full namespace name.

If you dont want to specify long qualifiers all the time, you can shorten them like this:

```
Apple.Berry.Cheese.Cake cake = new Apple.Berry.Cheese.Cake();
```

shortened:

```
using abc = Apple.Berry.Cheese;

abc.Cake cake = new abc.Cake();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Visual studio** gives you a lot of power and can easily let you pass over some concepts. One of the tools provided is that you can right click to add a using directive at the top of the code file which signals the compiler what class names will mean at compile time.

But if two namespaces have the same class name, and both are in use in the same class, then you have to explicitly tell the compiler in each case what to use.